# Request linking of a specific node in xText

Tags: xtext

In my DSL I have a cunstruct such as:

```
myInstance.abc == 2 -> [...]

template myTemplate
    const int abc;
endtemplate

instance myInstance of myTemplate with abc:=2;
```

The creation of instances can be anywhere in the code since instances are static and won't change. Ever. So I want the placement of instances in the code to not matter.

But during scoping the first line will be served first so in order to do so I need myInstance to be linked to myTemplate beforehand. But the linking hasn't reached that part of the code yet. Is there a way to request linking of a specific node from within my custom ScopeProvider?

EDIT:
Something such as

```
SomeLibrary.ensureLinked((EObject)templateInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scope provider you have access to the whole DOM. So just scan the DOM for all occurrences of "instance" and provide these as scope. You are not limited to the element given as parameter to your scope provider, but you can navigate the DOM to any element reachable.

The scope provider usually returns all elements applicable for the current scope. xText then by their name. So you usually define scope providers for whole blocks, not for each element inside a block. In the implementation you have to navigate through the DOM part representing your block.